# Нужно ли тире после "чаще всего"?

Tags: пунктуация

электромагнитные газовые клапаны (ЭГК), предназначенные для автоматического перекрытия газопровода при возникновении каких-либо аварийных ситуаций, чаще всего — по сигналу от СЗ об утечке газа;

сейсмические клапаны (чаще всего – механические, хотя встречаются и аналоги с электронным управлением)

Answer (score 2):

В подобных случаях тире указывает на пропущенный для лаконичности оборот. Ко второй фразе оно подходит: вполне можно догадаться, что полностью было бы "чаще всего это клапаны механические". Но в первой фразе вместо тире стилистически лучше написать всё полностью: "чаще всего такое перекрытие производится по сигналу...", поскольку иначе поначалу приходится разбираться, то ли аварийные ситуации чаще всего по сигналу случаются, то ли клапаны чаще всего предназначены для автоматического перекрытия, хотя и не всегда.

Answer (score 0):

По основному правилу тире не нужно. Можно поставить интонационное тире.